# Batch File to find and copy a file to a destination other than the current Directory

Tags: batch-file, copy, cmd, move

I finished a Java Program, and now i'm creating a Batch File to set it up. I have no great knowledge of batch files, and CMD commands, thats why im asking this question :).

This is what i have already :

```
@echo off
C:
md \Calc
D:
cd Calculator
move D:\Calculator\Calc.jar C:\Calc\
```

However This Requires that the user places the folder "calculator" into D:\, which can be inconvenient, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Hi - Did you know that you can set it up so the user can just double-click the .jar file (or a shortcut of the .jar file) to invoke your app?  I think there are many better ways to go than a .bat file.  IMHO...  I'd recommend "do nothing" (just give them the .jar).  Here are other alternatives: [Create Windows installer for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396778/create-windows-installer-for-java-programs)

Comment: Thanks For The Reply Paul, However I tried double - clicking on the .jar and nothing happens. Im only a beginner programmer, so its just a command line application for now, perhaps you could show me how to set it up the way you said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PUSHD C:` to change directory and then `POPD` will return you to the previously current directory.

Comment: Thanks for that Neil, that helps alot :). Also, is there a way to make cmd find a file, then move to that directory?

Comment: You can use `FOR /R` to find a file and in the controlled statement you can use the `%~dp` prefix to extract just the drive and path from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

to search for a file, and copy it to the stated location:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b/s d:\calc.jar') do copy "%%a" c:\calc\
```

This has the issue that it will copy every `calc.jar` it finds to the location (overwriting the old one).

Look at the output of `dir /b/s d:\calc.jar` to see what files it will find

Answer (score 0):

To make a .jar file run by double-clicking, set a file association in Windows:

> http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.com/2005/10/setting-jar-file-association.html
>
> ```
> Open the Windows Explorer, from the Tools select 'Folder Options...'
> Click the File Types tab, scroll down and select JAR File type.
> Press the Advanced button.
> In the Edit File Type dialog box, select open in Actions box and click Edit...
> Press the Browse button and navigate to the location the Java interpreter javaw.exe.
> In the Application used to perform action field, needs to display something similar to C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_04\bin\javaw.exe"
> ```
>
> -jar "%1" % (Note: the part starting with 'javaw' must be exactly like that; the other part of the path name can vary depending on which
>   version of Java you're using) then press the OK buttons until all the
>   dialogs are closed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however i want this app to be distributable, so that people don't have to set file association, just so they have to click an .exe, however the way i am doing it rquires the users to place the file in D:\ then run setup.bat then run the Calc.bat. Then it runs the app.