# Create Windows installer on non-Windows system

Tags: java, windows, installation

I want to create an Windows installer for a Java application, though the native executables already exist and hence it simplifies to installing any kind of files. This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396778/create-windows-installer-for-java-programs), but with following restrictions:

- the Windows installer must be a native one, it must require an installed or bundled JRE
- the installer creation must be platform independent, so it can be run on Windows, Linux or OS X (e.g. Java/ANT-based installer creation)

Currently, depending on our specific product, we are using WiX and InnoSetup, but both require the build process to be running on Windows. I want to avoid using Windows or Wine, but search a tool which already does it on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Wine compatability for Wix & InnoSetup? Also you can make scripts that start virtual machines to do stuff like this automatically.  I have a Linux system that makes Windows XP/Windows 7 installation files using a combination of Wine and VirtualBox scripting.