# How to add/remove java application in registry key using dos

Tags: java, command-line, installation, registrykey

I have created a java application and an installer. 
I want to add my program in registry key using dos command in order to be displayed in control panel.

I don't want to use any application for this. I want to do it from dos.

Later i want to create an uninstaller for the same purpose.

Any idea?

Comment: You mean dos like Windows command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Windows Installer for Java Programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396778/create-windows-installer-for-java-programs)

Comment: Yes, windows command line