# How to create (Java application ) JAR to installer for windows?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

How can I create (Java application ) JAR to installer for windows?
For 32-bit and for 64-bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Windows Installer for Java Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396778/create-windows-installer-for-java-programs)

Answer (score 1):

First create a runnable jar , you can easily create with help of any ide like eclipse or even from cmd.
Then create an exe with help of launch4j or install4j